# How to make gdb not ask me "y or n"?

Tags: debugging, gdb

When I use GDB command `add-symbol-file` to load the symbol, GDB always asks me 'y or n', like this:

```
gdb> add-symbol-file mydrv.ko 0xa0070000
add symbol table from file "mydrv.ko" at
        .text_addr = 0xa0070000
(y or n)
```

How to make it not ask and execute quietly?

Comment: Try `set confirm off`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, Thanks very much. It works!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

gdb will ask you to confirm certain commands, if the value of the `confirm` setting is `on`. From [Optional Warnings and Messages](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Messages_002fWarnings.html):

> - set confirm off
>     Disables confirmation requests. Note that running GDB with the --batch option (see -batch) also automatically disables confirmation requests.
> - set confirm on
>     Enables confirmation requests (the default).
> - show confirm
>     Displays state of confirmation requests.

That's a single global setting for `confirm`. In case you want to disable confirmation just for the `add-symbol-file` command, you can define two [hooks](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Hooks.html), which will run before and after the command:

```
(gdb) define hook-add-symbol-file
set confirm off
end
(gdb) define hookpost-add-symbol-file
set confirm on
end
```

If you want to disable confirmation just for a single invocation of a command, precede it with the `server` keyword, which is part of gdb's [annotation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Server-Prefix.html#Server-Prefix) system.